# Creating admin table (backend) in Joomla - for own plugin/module/component

Tags: php, joomla, backend

I want to create an custom table in the `/administrator` (back-end) with my plugin (or component/module, if plug-ins cannot do it for me), so I can populate it with some data that administrator can manage.

By *table*, I mean the table with form and default buttons (like filter ect). The example of such table added by VirtueMark2 component to Joomla: [image]

I have noticed some common elements of all such tables in Joomla back-end (like e.g. filter, sorting, same buttons, style, html structure), so I guess they are not written "from hand", but by some special commands/functions/methods called by plugin/component/module.

I already know how to add custom fields to my plugin, via XML file of that plugin, like:[image]

Comment: You need to create a component extension that creates and manages its tables. I recommend following tutorial: http://docs.joomla.org/J3.2:Developing_a_MVC_Component/Developing_a_Basic_Component

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Joomla supports a variety of extension types, [Components](http://docs.joomla.org/Component), [Modules](http://docs.joomla.org/Modules) and [Plugins](http://docs.joomla.org/Plugin) being the most commonly considered extensions. Other extension types supported by the Joomla Extension Manager are [Templates](http://docs.joomla.org/Templates) and Libraries.

A [Joomla Component](http://docs.joomla.org/Component) provides "the main functional units of Joomla!; they can be seen as mini-applications". The [Joomla Doc's website](http://docs.joomla.org/) has a [Component Development Portal](http://docs.joomla.org/Portal%3aComponent_Development) that includes all the [relevant tutorials](http://docs.joomla.org/Developing_a_MVC_Component) for version [2.5.x](http://docs.joomla.org/J2.5%3aDeveloping_a_MVC_Component) of Joomla and the [newer 3.x versions](http://docs.joomla.org/J3.2%3aDeveloping_a_MVC_Component).

From your screenshots you're using Joomla 2.5.x.

When creating an extension, the Joomla installer will look for an [install SQL file](http://docs.joomla.org/J2.5%3aDeveloping_a_MVC_Component/Using_the_database) in which you can define the creation of your table and any standard records. Additionally, it will look for a [PHP script to execute as part of the installation/update](http://docs.joomla.org/J2.5%3aDeveloping_a_MVC_Component/Adding_an_install-uninstall-update_script_file), called `script.php` which allows you to execute methods on, first `install()`, or subsequent `update()`'s and to run a `preflight()` check or a `postflight()` clean up. There's even an `uninstall()` method you can use to clean-up after the user decides to uninstall your extension.